# iOS 7, Text Field Capitalization All Characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, ios7

i have try to enable Capitalization All Characters in a Text Field in the Storyboard Attributes Inspector, actualy it's not working.

Before working in iOS 6

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have check that now and in fact if i use the screen keyboard it's woking corectly, with Mac keybord not...

Thx to Zev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior seems a little different between iOS 6 and 7, at least in the simulator:

iOS 6 Simulator: typing on the onscreen keyboard results in capital letters directly. Typing with the computer’s keyboard results in lowercase letters and an autocorrect suggestion that would convert it to uppercase.

iOS 7 Simulator: typing on the onscreen keyboard results in capital letters directly (same as iOS 6). However, typing with the computer keyboard seems kind of broken. You get lowercase letters, but the autocorrect seems to offer a suggestion only for the last letter in a word.

Are you seeing your problem when typing with the onscreen keyboard, or your computer keyboard in the simulator?

Comment: HI, thx for replay i have check that now and in fact if i use the screen keyboard it's woking corectly, with Mac keybord not...

Thx alot!